# How do I write a universal/flexible regex in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am learning regex. As you know, people may have middle name or not. I want to write a flexible regex to compile and use in the future. However, I am unable to do so. Any advice and/or help would be highly appreciated. Below is my regex for name without middle name.

```
import re
p = re.compile(r"\W+\s+(?P<firstname>\w+)\s+(?P<lastname>\w+)")
name = "John Drell"
m = p.search(name)
```

I do not have any problem for name without middle name. However, I am unable write correct flexible for names which may have or not middle name. Here is one of my testing code.

```
import re
p = re.compile(r"\W+\s+(?P<firstname>\w+)\s+(?:P<middlename>[A-Z]*)(?P<lastname>\w+)")
name = "John M. Drell"
m = p.search(name)
```

This script only allows name with middle name, otherwise I got error message: 'NonType" object has no attribute 'groups'.

I highly appreciate it if you could correct me.

Comment: Try `^(?P<firstname>\S+)(?:\s+(?P<middlename>\S+))?\s+(?P<lastname>\S+)$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vsoVbX/1). Also, why not just `.split()`?

Comment: Yeah, splitting on whitespace is the right solution to this problem. The first lesson of regex is to avoid it when possible ;)

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: But even when spIitting on whitespace be aware that people can have several middle names, not just zero or one, and surnames can contain spaces.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! I got it. I would mark it as the best answer if you could put your comments as an answer.

Comment: @PaulBecotte thanks for your comments!

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thanks for your link.

Comment: @BoarGules, thanks for your valuable comments and awareness.

Comment: Looks like there is a more versatile answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split()`:

```py
names = ["John M. Drell", "John Drell"]
for name in names:
    firstname, *middlenames, lastname = name.split()
    print(f'First name: {firstname}, Middle name(s): {" ".join(middlenames)}, Last name: {lastname}')
```

See [Python proof](https://ideone.com/tmB3sg).

With regex, learn to use optional groups and `\S` to match any non-whitespace characters:

```py
^(?P<firstname>\S+)(?:\s+(?P<middlename>\S+(?: +\S+)*))?\s+(?P<lastname>\S+)$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/N08ax1/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<firstname>           group and capture to "firstname":
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of "firstname"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?P<middlename>            group and capture to "middlename":
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t,
                               \f, and " ") (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         +                       ' ' (1 or more times (matching the
                                 most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t,
                                 \f, and " ") (1 or more times
                                 (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of "middlename"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<lastname>             group and capture to "lastname":
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of "lastname"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```